# -1 month não volta para o mês anterior - PHP

Tags: php, data, strtotime

Usava o `strtotime()` para voltar ao mês anterior e pegar sempre o ultimo dia do mês anterior, fazia desta forma:

```
$data_teste = date('Y-m-t', strtotime('-1 month'));
```

E vinha dando certo até hoje (31-10-2018), ao invés de voltar para o dia 30-09-2018 ele mostrou o dia 31-10-2018, aparentemente a função volta 30 dias e não para "o mês anterior" como eu pensava que ela fazia. Alguém sabe uma saída para esta situação?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você utiliza formatos relativos, deve "relativizar" o resultado.

Sendo hoje `31/10/2018`, utilizando `-1 month` ou `last month`, a data será `31/09/2018`.

Quando essa data é convertida para time, ou qualquer outra função de data, ela é interpretada como `01/10/2018`.

No seu código é fácil interpretar que você quer sempre o último dia do mês, nesse caso, utilize uma abordagem mais direta:

```
$date_teste = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of last month'));
```

Ou

```
$date_teste = new DateTime('last day of last month');
```

Veja os exemplos: https://3v4l.org/SUHoX

Comment: Quando usei o primeiro exemplo que você disse acima, ele me retornou para o ultimo dia do ultimo mês do ultimo ano que o PHP consegue voltar kkkk, acho q se deve ao fato da versão do PHP que sou obrigado a usar ser a 5.1.6 e ele entendeu de forma diferente

Comment: Existiram várias mudanças entre o PHP 5.0.0 e 5.3.0. Algumas interpretações do formato relativo mudaram nesse período.